# Open Cassandra for remote connection only for single IP, and connect using python

Tags: python, cassandra

I'm trying to write a script to connect to the remote Cassandra DB in python.
I'm using `flask_cqlalchemy`. Cassandra is set up on a remote server with SSH access and while connecting to the Cassandra, it's giving:

```
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'IP:9042': ConnectionRefusedError(61, "Tried connecting to [('IP', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

And `9042` port is open in the firewall.
I tried using "TablePlus tool" and it's connecting perfectly.

Comment: what are the values of `rpc_address` & `broadcast_rpc_address` in your `cassandra.yaml` file ?

Comment: `rpc_address: localhost` & `broadcast_rpc_address ` is not set. It's commented.

Answer (score 0):

Your Cassandra node is configured to accept connections from `localhost` - to allow remote access you need to set `rpc_address` to the IP address of the host, but you need to be careful with it, as then anybody can access your Cassandra node (especially if it's in the cloud).

Plus, if you configure only `rpc_address`, then it won't accept connections on `localhost` - in this case you can set `rpc_address` to `0.0.0.0`, and `broadcast_rpc_address` to node's IP.

Comment: I've already tried this, but I only want it to be open for a single IP, not for public access. Can I specify only a single IP address to access the Cassandra?

Comment: you can add a firewall rule to give access from specific IP only

Comment: Can't I add a user for a particular IP like in SQL?

Comment: No - I'm not aware of the IP-based authentication